# Cannot connect to KB external service using NodePort

Tags: kubernetes

I cannot seem to find why couldn't connect to an endpoint I have exposed via NodePort. While the container is running as expected when running `kubectl logs <pod>`, I am unable to reach:

`http://<node ip>:30100/<valid endpoint form container>`

where the `<node ip>` is the ip from running `kubectl get nodes -o wide` under `INTERNAL IP`.

I am unsure whether the problem resides in the deployment yaml. Below is my single deployment that I've applied to the cluster:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-app-deployment
  labels:
    app: auth-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth-app
          image: <working image>
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-app-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: auth-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30100
```

Also, here are the results from running `kubectl get all`:

```
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/auth-app-deployment-58cd68d8cf-mjpph   1/1     Running   0          29m

NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
service/auth-app-service   NodePort    10.104.172.176   <none>        80:30100/TCP   138m
service/kubernetes         ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        150m

NAME                                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/auth-app-deployment   1/1     1            1           138m

NAME                                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/auth-app-deployment-58cd68d8cf   1         1         1       29m
```

PS: I am using `minikube`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is coming across the same issue with minikube, you can use the I fixed the by using `minikube service <service>` command which exposes the service to localhost, much like the port forward command in kubectl.

In my case, the command looks like this:

```
minikube service auth-app-service
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a NodePort service you can't use the cluster IP, which is different from the node IP's.
Assuming you only one have 1 node (bc you are using minikube) you need to use the ip you get from `kubectl describe nodes` under the addresses section, use InternalIP value.

Your url will be `http://<node_ip>:30100/<valid endpoint form container>`

Comment: This is what I was doing. I edited the question accordingly. The initial question was misleading that was my bad

Comment: I fixed the by using `minikube service <app service in question>`